# why date format give true value using momentjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am trying to validate formate . but I am getting **true** value .

why ?

```
  var a = "11-01-2022";
  console.log("sss", moment(a, "YYYY-mm-DD").isValid());
```

Expected output is : false. here I am getting true why ?

```
var a = "2022-01-11";
      console.log("sss", moment(a, "YYYY-mm-DD").isValid());
Expected output is : true.
```

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-cookies-npsit?file=/src/App.js:85-165

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable strict parsing. It's the third argument in the moment function.

```
console.log("sss", moment(a, "YYYY-mm-DD", true).isValid()); //Outputs false
```

> Strict parsing requires that the format and input match exactly, including delimiters. Strict parsing is frequently the best parsing option.

[Updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-framework-l9upc)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly pass third parameter for parsing.

```
console.log("sss", moment(a, "YYYY-mm-DD", true).isValid());
```